# Required attribute and init handler in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have the following in my component:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true" />
```

Component's controller simply calls apex auraEnabled method (which is fetches one record of Camping_Item__c type) and sets `v.item` attribute.

When I try to run an app with this component, I get an error:

> [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize
>   application.

If I remove `required="true"` from `aura:attribute` all goes fine.

Why is that? Is it possible to use the `required="true"` property with init handler?

Comment: Did you try by providing default value for required attribute?

Comment: Yes, with the default value I got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that if you set required="true" then the app or component that declares your component needs to provide the item. For example if your component is called "Camponent" in namespace "c" then the parent app/component would need to have:

```
<c:Camponent item="{!v.someCampingItemThatAlreadyExists}" />
```

Now, if the parent's init method fills in that value, then you're fine because it won't even attempt to create the c:Camponent until the init method has finished.

Comment: Now it makes sense, parent app or component should provide required attribute value. I tried it and it works fine, thanks.